# Copy files from Remote Unix and Windows servers into HDFS without intermediate staging

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, biginsights

How can I copy files from remote Unix and Windows servers into HDFS without intermediate staging from the command line?

Comment: There is no standard command which achieves this. Good work arounds are given [here](http://one-line-it.blogspot.com/2013/05/hadoop-copy-directly-to-hdfs-from.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270509/putting-a-remote-file-into-hadoop-without-copying-it-to-local-disk). Hope this helps.

Comment: @buckeyeosu .. Could you please share some efficient way to achieve this. I got stuck with same problem. I will also refer to other options as mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command:

```
hadoop fs -cp /user/myuser/copyTestFolder/* hdfs://remoteServer:8020/user/remoteuser/copyTestFolder/
```

or vice versa to copy from server to local machine.


You can also read the [hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#cp).

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebHDFS and cURL to upload files.  This will not require having any hadoop binaries on your client, just a cURL or cURL like client.  The BigInsights Knowledge Center has information on how to administer the file system using the [HttpFS REST APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.admin.doc/doc/admin_fileupload_rest_apis.html).