# scp remote file into hadoop without copying it to edge node

Tags: unix, hadoop, ssh, scp, copying

Want to copy a file from a remote server to hadoop without copying to edge node.

1.Per below article we can do it in 2 step by first doing scp to local edge node and then perform hdfs fs command to move from edge node to hdfs
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Import-data-from-remote-server-to-HDFS/td-p/233148

2.Per below article we can do ssh cat, but we have files like .gz which cannot be CAT
[putting a remote file into hadoop without copying it to local disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270509/putting-a-remote-file-into-hadoop-without-copying-it-to-local-disk)

But I am looking for a 3rd option where we can scp instead of ssh CAT and copy to hadoop without copying to Edge node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop doesnt have an SCP upload feature.

If you want to get files in without an edge node or SSH, then that's what WebHDFS or the NFSGateway offer

Comment: I dont see a copy option provided in WebHDFS. Can you please any link/ example command to achieve this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You POST a file, not copy

Answer (score -1):

Transfer using pipe

mkfifo  - this creates pipe on local server (this doesn't store any data)

try
mkfifo <pipename - some path on your server where ssh keys are present> | scp :  | hdfs dfs -put  | rm

Comment: Please improve your answer to be more readable. Write the code part in a code format